# Example for Spring Cloud Consul with Ribbon for client side load balancing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, service-discovery, consul

I see that spring-cloud-consul is live in spring.io [https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/27/spring-cloud-consul-1-0-0-m1-available-now] but I hardly see any reference examples.

I am mainly looking for Service Registration and Service Discovery with Consul and Ribbon as client side load balancer. Could someone give a sample application or an example to refer. I also checked in the git repository for spring-cloud-consul, didn't find any examples there[https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul]

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the main repo, [spring-cloud-consul-sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-sample/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/sample/SampleConsulApplication.java), that uses the `LoadBalancerClient` of which there is a ribbon implementation that will use consul to populate the server list.

Comment: I tried that too. Its a half baked code, I will not use it until all the issues are fixed. Dependency resolution has lot of issues. Either use 1.0.0.M1 or 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT of spring-cloud-consul, none of them are resolving the dependencies cleanly. Why is it still part of spring.io when its not completely done... !!

Comment: well, you are right. 1.0.0.M1 is pre-release version, so there can be problems. maybe the best way is to report problems (with specific details) to github owner.

Comment: @PPK it is a milestone release, not production ready yet.  I'd love to know what dependency resolution issues you have.  I can't help if you just say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find much information about Consul and Ribbon, but I have found more information about Eueka (it's used by Netflix and it also does service registration/distcovery similiar to Consul). This Spring project seems to be a lot more active. Info about it can be found here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/

This blog post demonstrates how to use spring cloud with Eueka and Ribbon: https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring

There is also a repo for the tutorial: https://github.com/paulc4/microservices-demo

If you still want to use Consul instead of Eueka, here is a sample project, you should be able to use this along with the blog post above to build a working example: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/tree/master/spring-cloud-consul-sample

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a demo project using Spring Cloud Consul and Spring Cloud Netflix.
I'm using Consul as a service registry, and Ribbon/Hystrix/Feign are used to simplify API service clients.

The project is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/alexandreroman/number2words.